# PHP of custom field inside PHP Tag

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I´m display a slider that get´s the images from custom field, now I need that the slider shows different images depending on the language (es - ca):

This is the code of the slider:

```
        <a href="<?php the_field('slider_home_1_enlace') ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_field('slider_home_1'); ?>">
        </a>
```

So I´m creating a conditional tag to load images depending of the language of qtranslate plugin:

```
        <?php
        _e('<!--:es-->
                <a href="<?php the_field('slider_home_1_enlace') ?>">
                    <img src="<?php <the_field('slider_home_1'); ?>">
                </a>
            <!--:-->
            <!--:ca-->
                <a href="<?php the_field('slider_home_1_enlace_ca') ?>">
                    <img src="<?php the_field('slider_home_1_ca'); ?>">
                </a>
            <!--:-->');
        ?>
```

I´m a php begginer so I see the problem maybe that the php is inside another php, because this way its not working, if i just put text between   tags it works properly for the language.

Any ideas how to syntax this?

Comment: you should complete each php tag.before writing new php tag lik <?php code here ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check language first, using *if - else*

detect the language and store it to the variable named **$language** and then check the condition as below.

```
<?php
if(qtrans_getLanguage()=="es"){
?>
  <a href="<?php the_field('slider_home_1_enlace'); ?>">
      <img src="<?php the_field('slider_home_1'); ?>">
  </a>
<?php
} else if(qtrans_getLanguage()=="ca"){
?>
  <a href="<?php the_field('slider_home_1_enlace_ca'); ?>">
      <img src="<?php the_field('slider_home_1_ca'); ?>">
  </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @diego how you are detecting the language selected? I mean how would u know which language to show?

Comment: i'm just using qtranslate and with this  it detects the language "<!--:es-->" i'm not using anymore

Comment: if you are using qtranslate then check the if condition like this `if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='en')`

Comment: @diego - check the edited answer !! i am editing now !! give it a try as i am not a wordpress user and haven't used qtranslate before. But still try this.

Comment: @diego - My pleasure !! Enjoy !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have php-tags inside each other.

Use basic string concatenation to combine your strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it that way. Compare: (I guess that the_field() returns the string ;))

```
<a href="'.the_field("slider_home_1_enlace").'">
    <img src="'.the_field("slider_home_1").'" />
</a>
```

There are multiple mistakes. At first, you can't use the

```
'.(your things here).'
```

Second, theres a < in your fourth line and you forget to close your img-tag.

Comment: this doesn´t gives error, but the problem is that it shows the url of the image instead of displaying it :S do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? Most browsers display the path, if the image doesn't exist.
Note: I had a typo in my code. Try again.

Comment: Hm. The img-tag is correct; if the path is too, I don't know. Please check the resulting html!

Comment: the resulting html is that it displays the full text plain of the "a" and the "img", not with the tags

Answer (score 0):

First, install the qTranslate Wordpress plugin.

Then, you can try this:

```
<?php

    $slider_img_fields_langs = array(
        '',
        'ca',
        'es',
    );

    $lang = qtrans_getLanguage();
    if( !in_array( $lang, $slider_img_fields_langs ) );
        $lang = '';

    echo '
<a href="' . the_field( 'slider_home_1_enlace' . $lang ) . '">
    <img src="' . the_field( 'slider_home_1' . $lang ) . '">
</a>';

?>
```